# Group set of jvmarg

Tags: ant

in my build.xml I have two targets which are quite similar. One thing that makes them similar is that they both share a large set of jvmargs. Right now I am repeating this set of jvmargs under each target. It feels wrong with duplicating the set like that, is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Ant build.xml issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323081/java-ant-build-xml-issue)

Comment: macrodef's are the way to avoid replication and enable reuse in ANT. http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html